# a contour integral involving Sign function related to Lerch Zeta function

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, fourier-series, zeta-functions

I have been trying to evaluate the following integral using contour method 
\begin{equation}
G(\tau)=\oint\frac{dz}{2\pi i} \frac{e^{{-z \tau}}}{z+ sign(Imz)}\frac{1}{e^{\beta z}+1}, 
\end{equation}

where $\tau \in (-\beta,\beta)$, and the contour is (as determined by the discontinuity of the sign function) the semi-circle enclosing the whole upper plane plus the semi-circle that encloses the lower half plane. The real axis is cut out as a branch cut.

The integral arises from trying to evaluate the infinite sum that can be written as a Lerch Zeta function
\begin{equation}
G(\tau)=\frac{1}{\beta}\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{{-i\omega_n \tau}}}{-i \omega_n-\text{sign}{(\omega_n})},
\end{equation}

where where $\omega_n$=$(2n+1)\pi$/$\beta$.

Comment: Does it help to write it as $$ \sum_{\substack{n~{\rm odd} \\ n>0}} \frac{2i \sin(n\pi\tau/\beta)}{in\pi/\beta+1}~? $$

Comment: @runway44 I did try this, but then the contour integral method does not work, since one must try to enclose only poles along the positive imaginary axis, but the second term in the integrand has poles over all the imaginary axis. Without the +1 factor, this would work though.